# variables in bash profile

Tags: bash, unix

I am not too familiar with bash_profiles, and am setting up some aliases in my bash_profile like so:

```
alias nrc='npm run server:cloud'
alias cnrc='cd path/to/repo && npm run server:cloud'
```

Is there any way to use `nrc` in the second command (cnrc) instead of writing out `npm run server:cloud`? what's the syntax for variables in bash_profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use functions instead.

```
nrc () { npm run server:cloud; }
cnrc () { cd path/to/repo && nrc; }
```

Comment: I was able to do alias cnrc='cd path/to/repo && $(nrc)' , what's incorrect about that?

Comment: @devdropper87 It's not *incorrect*, but it does force the shell to run the command in a subshell, which in general could cause problems if your alias included code to change the value of a variable; the change would be lost when the subshell exits. Unless you can provide a good reason why a function won't work, prefer a function to an alias. Aliases aren't even *shorter*: `alias` and the `=` sign are 6 characters; `()`, `{`, and `;}` are only 5 :)